# Using a Javascript variable in HTML <a> link

Tags: javascript, html

My code goes something like this -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>


    <script type='text/javascript'>

    var random_generator;
    document.write('Random Selection: ');
    var arr=['One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten'];
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    random_generator=arr[randomnumber];
    document.write(random_generator+ '<br>');


    </script>

<style type="text/css">

</style>
<a href='www.xyz.com/Index1/Index2/Variable/Index4'>Good Morning</a>
</head>
<body> 
</body>  
</html>
```

In place of Variable in the  tag, I want to use random_generator Javascript variable. How do I do that? Thanks in Advance.

NOTE: random_generator doesn't replace the entire link. Only a part of the link (/Variable/). Depending on this value, the user is shown different pages.

Comment: In place of the href or the text? Sorry I'm confused.

Comment: In place of Variable in the href link. Different address link depending on the value of Variable ( /Variable/ ) in the href tag.

Comment: My apologies. I missed that. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or maybe you could just write the link as inline js.

```
​<script>
document.write('<a href="http://www.xyz.com/Index1/Index2/' + random_generator + '/Index4">hello</a>');
</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i understand your problem.  But the following should work if you are trying to dynamically set the link to href (assuming you are not using jquery).

```
<a href='http://www.xyz.com/Index1/Index2/Variable/Index4' id="index">Good Morning</a>
<script>
    var newUrl = document.getElementById('index').href;
    newUrl = newUrl.replace("Variable", random_generator);
    document.getElementById('index').href = newUrl;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to update the dom element when the script gets executed

First you must give an id to your href

`<a href="#" id="myHref"`

and then

`$('#myHref').attr('href', variable)`

Or you can change the link text
`var varText = "This is a link"; $('#myHref').text(varText);`

Comment: Or just document.getElementById

Comment: You mean `$('#myHref').attr('href', variable)` ?

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure this will wrk

```
   document.getElementById('myHref').href = variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this would not be possible. You could do one of two things:

1 Change the HREF attribute when the document loads. With JQuery you could do something like

```
$(function() {
 $('a').attr('href', 'www.xyz.com/Index1/Index2/' + random_generator + '/Index4');
});
```

2 Catch the click event and redirect it with javascript, this would mean even if the user clicked the link multiple times without refreshing the page it would be random.

```
$(function() {
 $('a').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location = 'www.xyz.com/Index1/Index2/' + random_generator + '/Index4';
 });
});
```

If you don't wish you use jquery I'm sure there's plenty examples online to do this with plain javascript.

Comment: Appreciate your response. Thank You.